# How to use parameters without values with jQuery BBQ plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

I need to define and to read hash values like

```
#page1&filter=1-1-0 
#filter=1-1-0 (if page number is omitted)
#page1 (if filter is not defined)
```

I.e. page number will be part of the parameter and will be without value.
How to work (get and set) with such parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution with BBQ plugin usage ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/bWycv/)):

```
var hash = $.deparam.fragment();
var page = 'page1';
$.each(hash, function(i, val) {
    if (i.indexOf('page') != -1) page = i;
});
var filter = (hash.filter==undefined) ? '0-0-0' : hash.filter;

// update hash
$.bbq.pushState('#' + page + '&filter=' + filter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the contents of the string after the hash in the URL with `window.location.hash`.

You'll then need to so a little bit of parsing to get your key-value pairs. Something like the code below:

```
function getParameters(){
    params = {}
    var keyValuePairs = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
    for (x in keyValuePairs){
        var split = keyValuePairs[x].split('=', 2);
        params[split[0]] = (split[1]) ? decodeURI(split[1]) : "";
    }
    return params;
}

function setParameters(key, value){
    var params = getParameters();
    params[key] = value;
    var hashString = ""
    for (x in params){
        if (params[x]){
            hashString += "&" + x + "=" + encodeURI(params[x]);
        } else {
            hashString += "&" + x;
        }
    }
    window.location.hash = hashString.substr(1);
}
```

You could read the read your "filter" parameter with something like:

```
var parameters = getParameters();
console.log(parameters.filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, extols. Is there any way to simplify the same with jQuery BBQ plugin? ;) Also, what I don't like with your approach - if page is not defined, then hash looks like `#&filter=1-1-326` - ideally, there shouldn't be `&` sign. Can it be fixed?